# User authentication using Node.js and flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter

I want to authenticate users using Node.js as a backend and flutter as the frontend. I don't know which one is better using a session and cookie or using JWT.

And how can I save the cookie in flutter app if I used cookie or JWT?

Please help me??

Comment: they are two different things. why not use firebase auth? its free and its easy to integrate google and apple sign in.

Answer (score 1):

1. personally i like to use JWT , just because its more secure.
2. to store JWT token on Flutter App, u can use plugin shared_preferances.
   [documentation of shared preferances](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

3. Authentication has nothing to do with node js or any other language or framework. Authentication process is almost same in every language, just authenticate user based on username/password or email/password pair.

Comment: Thanks  and also I want to keep the user logged in until he logs out. Any ideas on how we can do that? I would appreciate the help.

Comment: You can store the token using shared preferences plug in and later u can check whether token is there or not, if token is there, treat user as authenticated else redirect user to login screen. there is lots of tutorial on YouTube for shared preferences .

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help.